# How to set a layout using spinner

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a layout like the below picture. How can I set the drop-down like this with cancel option. I am using spinner to show the drop-down but cannot set the layout like this.

[image]

Can anyone help me to create a drop-down like this. I also want to create an expand button for a list item which will open the content in a new page. My aim is to set all the available settings in a single page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then use `PreferenceActivity`. In fact, that's a standard preference screen.

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceScreen.html
- http://jetpad.org/2011/01/creating-a-preference-activity-in-android/

You can take a look at the API Demo app which is in the Android SDK. There you can learn how to create this kind of screens (either from XML or code). It has many advantages... for instance, you won't have to worry about persisting the settings... the OS will do that for you.

Comment: Absolutely what I was about to post as an answer! :P  You got quick fingers @Cristian!

Comment: Lol :) you have to be fast in SO... for sure.

Comment: Thanks guys... let me check this! :)

Comment: API Demo helped me a lot to understand about the preferences screen. Thanks a lot Cristian. I have one more doubt. How can we get the value set using preference activity. I have tried to get the value using sharedPrefernces.getInt("pref_key", 0); but its showing the default value '0'. :(

Comment: How are you initializing the `sharedPrefernces` variable?

Comment: Hi Cristian,
Thank u very much for your support. The problem has been solved now :)  

I've used this method to get the sharedPreferences

SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);